# .Net Compact Framework 2.0 touch and nice controls

Tags: .net, compact-framework, .net-2.0

I would like to know if somebody knows free custom nice controls for .NET Compact Framework 2.0.

There are nice controls as Manila Interface SDK (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=566188), Sense Interface SDK (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=648906) and so on for free, but they work only on .NET CF 3.5.

Furthermore, there are others that you have to pay for them and for .NET CF 2.0 and 3.5 (Resco or Touch Control Suite).

And there is one called Fluid (http://fluid.codeplex.com/) but it's so complicated, there are not exactly controls (are classes added to a host control) and there is not much documentation to work with it.

Any nice controls for free and working in .NET CF 2.0? And with list sliders if it's possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered another nice library with controls for .net 2.0. With some backgrounds you can create nice buttons. Furthermore, there is a item list very nice: OpenNETCF. You can use the community edition for free.

http://www.opennetcf.com/sdf

Continue discovering...